# how can I clear a textbox and disable it if a condition is met in knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js

Is there any way, to combine the two following methods into one in knockoutjs?
What the code says is "if collectall checkbox is ticked then disable the text box and clear it".

```
self.CollectAll.subscribe(function(CollectAll) {
    if (CollectAll) {
         self.TonalitySize('');
    }
});
self.DisableSizeLimit = ko.computed(function (){
    return self.CollectAll();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `DisableSizeLimit` and `CollectAll` are always equivalent, then you don't need the extra observable.

```
self.CollectAll = ko.observable();
self.TonalitySize = ko.observable();

self.CollectAll.subscribe(function(CollectAll) {
    if (CollectAll) {
         self.TonalitySize('');
    }
});
```

You can just bind `CollectAll` to disable the text box.

```
<input data-bind="value: TonalitySize, disable: CollectAll" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// add a computed property for the value you want to display.
self.TonalitySizeDisplay = ko.computed({
    read: function () { return self.CollectAll() ? "" : self.TonalitySize(); },
    write: self.TonalitySize
});
self.DisableSizeLimit = ko.computed(self.CollectAll);


// bind to the display property
<textarea data-bind="value: TonalitySizeDisplay, enable: !DisableSizeLimit()" />
```

Comment: This doesn't combine them into one. It doesn't even do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just stick the logic for the `subscribe` in the `computed`. The computed is re-run whenever any observable change, so it will function just like a `subscribe` will

```
self.DisableSizeLimit = ko.computed(function (){
    if(self.CollectAll())
        self.TonalitySize('');
    return self.CollectAll();
});
```

I am not sure why you would *want* to do this though. Having them separated makes the behavior easier to see, is functionally equivalent, and is just better practice.